# Restoring azure snapshot causes downtime?

Tags: azure, snapshot, restore

I have a web app running on azure. If I, via portal, restore a backup/snapshot, will my site become unavailable for a period longer than the "warm-up"?

Comment: Why not give it a try with an alternate URL?

Comment: @EEAA i don't have the necessary permissions... i wanna pitch the idea to my boss... knowing if there's downtime or not would greatly help my case

Comment: Sounds like a great question for Azure support. Or whomever has the needed permissions.